# Sessions - servlets

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I have this particular piece of code and the problem is that the sessions arent working on it.

I checked out this post here at [Can't get the session in java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874091/cant-get-the-session-in-java-servlet), but it wasnt of much help....

here is the code for my servlet, the doGet. I have cookies enabled. I tried using Firefox, IE, and the built in browser of Eclipse, but it isn't working.

Is there anything to change here?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws      
ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
    String name=request.getParameter("userName");
    String email=request.getParameter("email");
    String ip=request.getRemoteAddr();
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
            //blah! blah! blah!
    session.setAttribute("savedUN",name);
    pw.println("<html>");
    pw.println("<head>");
    pw.println("<title>In servlet</title>");
    pw.println("</head>");
    pw.println("<body>");
    pw.println("Your name is"+name);
    pw.println("Your id is"+email);
    pw.println("Your Fucking IP is"+ip);
    pw.println("</body>");
    pw.println("</html>");
    pw.println("Request param has UN:"+name);
             //--------------help needed here!-----------------
    pw.println("Session param has UN:"+(String) session.getAttribute("savedUN"));   
}
```

Comment: Please, get the writer once, and use that temporary variable. This is almost unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the name stored in the Session when the username isn't passed.

Check for `null` username first.

```
if (name != null) {
  session.setAttribute("savedUN",name);
}
```

Comment: it worked ! :) ... @Ravi...can u just give me a short explanation about the overwriting part...im talking in the case where we input the required fields...and you said the case when its null...I understand what are you saying..but is this checking always needed and why is it exactly needed..? is this always necessary?

Comment: For the most part yes you would do a `null` check. Why? because you're saving something in session to retrieve it when it's not going to be available (like in your case when request parameter is missing). So, if you overwrite what you had saved with something that's missing then you're defeating the purpose of why you saved the thing in the first place. Hence, you check that you save it in session only when it's available. So the 1st time it's passed it initializes the session's name value and when it's passed on subsequent requests too it works like an update of the name saved in the session.